# Linux Terminal's Stdout

Tags: c, linux, terminal

- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 (Debian Wheezy)
- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

I am writing a function that uses ANSI escape sequences to get the current cursor position in an open terminal. Originally the function was hard coded to work on stdin and stdout. But I want the function to work on other terminals by taking a file descriptor as an argument. I just have no idea why or how some one would have the file descriptor for another terminal. I tried to use google but I do not really know how to ask my question. Anyway in my current test case I open up two gnome-terminals and run tty to find one of the terminal's stdin. Then I open that file up using open() in an application running in the other terminal. The application then requests the current cursor position and a response is sent to the other terminals stdin. I know that their is a response because I can see part of the response echoed to the other terminal which is strange because echoing should be disabled. So my question is, why do I receive only a partial response? And how would I make my function work as intended(find the value of the current cursor position in the other terminal).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int btccgetxy(int term, int *x, int *y)
{
    struct termios attr = {0};
    tcflag_t c_lflag = 0;
    cc_t vtime = 0;
    cc_t vmin = 0;
    int tmpy = 0;
    int tmpx = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char c = 0;

    //NOTE: This function is written a bit awkwardly
    //because the curent terminal settings at the call of the
    //function must be restored weither an error has occured
    //or not. So in order to avoid rewriting the cleanup code
    //I wrote the function on tracks. If at any point an error
    //should occur the function's flow will move to the end of
    //the function and restore the orginial settings.

    if(tcgetattr(term, &attr) == 0)
    {
        c_lflag = attr.c_lflag;
        vtime = attr.c_cc[VTIME];
        vmin = attr.c_cc[VMIN];

        if(attr.c_lflag & ECHO) attr.c_lflag ^= ECHO;
        if(attr.c_lflag & ICANON) attr.c_lflag ^= ICANON;
        attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

        if(tcsetattr(term, TCSAFLUSH, &attr) == 0)
        {
            if(write(term, "\033[6n", 4) == 4)
            {
                if(read(term, &c, 1) != 1 || c != '\033'
                || read(term, &c, 1) != 1 || c != '['
                || read(term, &c, 1) != 1 || c == ';')
                    ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;

                while(c != ';')
                {   
                    if(c < '0' || c > '9')
                    {
                        ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;
                        break;
                    }

                    tmpy = tmpy * 10 + (c - '0');

                    if(read(term, &c, 1) != 1)
                    {
                        ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(ret == 0)
                {
                    if(read(term, &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'R')
                    {
                        while(c != 'R')
                        {
                            if(c < '0' || c > '9')
                            {
                                ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;
                                break;
                            }

                            tmpx = tmpx * 10 + (c - '0');

                            if(read(term, &c, 1) != 1)
                            {
                                ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if(ret == 0)
                        {
                            *x = tmpx - 1;
                            *y = tmpy - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else ret = BTCC_ERESPONSE;
                }
            }
            else ret = BTCC_EREQUEST;
        }
        else ret = BTCC_ESET;
    }
    else ret = BTCC_ESAVE;

    attr.c_lflag = c_lflag;
    attr.c_cc[VTIME] = vtime;
    attr.c_cc[VMIN] = vmin;

    if(tcsetattr(term, TCSANOW, &attr) == -1)
        for(int count = 1; count <= BTCC_UNSETATTEMPTS; count++)
            if(tcsetattr(term, TCSANOW, &attr) == -1 && count == BTCC_UNSETATTEMPTS)
                return BTCC_EUNSET;

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    int term = 0;
    char c = 0;

    errno = 0;

    //You will need to run tty to find a valid path name
    if((term = open(<valid path name>, O_RDWR)) == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR(open)");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = btccgetxy(term, &x, &y);

    printf("ret = %i | (%i, %i)\n", ret, x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, with appropriate privileges, you can access file descriptor N (0, 1, …) of a process 1234 by accessing the file `/proc/1234/fd/1` (for N = 1, of course).  If that happens to be a terminal, then it works like a terminal.  Anyway, that's one way to get at file descriptors of another process.

The rest of your trouble is more nearly insoluble, I think.  Other processes have the terminal open for reading; it is a lottery which of the processes trying to read from the terminal gets the response sent by the terminal.  So far, you've lost out; that's partly bad luck, but mostly expected.

I don't think there's an easy way to stop another process reading the response you wanted to read, short of managing to hang (`SIGSTOP`) every other process that has the other terminal open for reading so that they can't read the data before your process does.  That really isn't practical as a solution, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you are saying it would be possible to do what I am asking but it would be difficult. I really just need to know if it is possible and theoretically necessary in some situation.

Comment: 'Appropriate privileges' is the term used in POSIX to mean (approximately) 'root privileges'; appropriate privileges can also be achieved via capabilities or by being the same user that has programs running connected to the other terminal. Yes, it could, more or less, be done — it certainly wouldn't be trivial (you'd have to identify all the processes that might be reading from the terminal, for example). Some people might take a dim view of you stopping their program even momentarily, even if you almost immediately release it again with SIGCONT.